# Laravel: how to insert a relationship (count) efficiently?

Tags: php, laravel-7

I'm developing a JSON API with Laravel 7.

I'm following a Repository - Gateway pattern.

I have two table in relation: agency and license (one agency (id) has many license (field agency_id), one license has only one agency)

I have in my Agencyrepository this:

```php
/**
     * Return the licenses list
     */
    public function licenses()
    {
        $data = $this->hasMany('App\Repositories\LicensesRepository', 'agency_id', 'id');
        return $data;
    }
```

And in my index method:

```php
public function index()
    {
        $data = $this->sort(request())->paginate($this->getPerPage());
        $collection = $data->getCollection();
        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $item->licenses;
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

I get the correct result:

```json
{
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "Ora 12",
            "is_active": true,
            "created_at": "2020-09-20T17:14:09.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-20T17:14:09.000000Z",
            "licenses": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Licenza numero 2",
                    "is_active": true,
                    "agency_id": 10,
                    "created_at": "2020-09-24T19:14:04.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-09-24T19:14:04.000000Z"
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "Licenza 3 per ora 12",
                    "is_active": true,
                    "agency_id": 10,
                    "created_at": "2020-09-25T06:30:50.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-09-25T06:30:50.000000Z"
                },
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "Licenza 4 per ora 12",
                    "is_active": true,
                    "agency_id": 10,
                    "created_at": "2020-09-25T06:31:01.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-09-25T06:31:01.000000Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "first_page_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/agencies?page=1",
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 9,
    "last_page_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/agencies?page=9",
    "next_page_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/agencies?page=2",
    "path": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/agencies",
    "per_page": 1,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "to": 1,
    "total": 9
}
```

1. If I delete the `licenses` method call in `index` method, I don't get anymore the associate licenses values (and... ok)
2. But, I want to add "simply" the license count (in this example "3") and not the entire result, possibly with a key `licenses_count`.

I did try:

```php
    public function licenses()
    {
        $data = $this->hasMany('App\Repositories\LicensesRepository', 'agency_id', 'id');
        return $data->count();
    }
```

But I get the exception `App\Repositories\AgenciesRepository::licenses must return a relationship instance`

Second try:

```php
public function index()
    {
        $data = $this->sort(request())->paginate($this->getPerPage());
        $collection = $data->getCollection();
        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $license_count = $item->licenses->count();
            echo $license_count;
            $item->licenses;
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

And in answer I get the number "3" but I don't know how to add it to the collection.

Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I got my result...

I added an accessor:

```php
public function getLicenseCount()
    {
        return $this->licenses()->count();
    }
```

And edited index method:

```php
/**
     * Return collection
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $data = $this->sort(request())->paginate($this->getPerPage());
        $collection = $data->getCollection();
        foreach ($collection as $key => $value) {
            $license_count = $value->getLicenseCount();
            $collection[$key]->license_count = $license_count;
        }
        return $data;
    }
```